# Move all files whose names contain a capital letter from source directory to target directory?

Tags: linux, command, wildcard, mv

How to write this linux command?
Move all files whose names contain a capital letter from source directory to target directory?

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, use this:

```
mv src/*[A-Z]* target/
```

Comment: It does not work correctly. Your * also matches the lower case letters. So the files with only lower case letters also picked up.

Comment: Did you enter the command _exactly verbatim_ with no spaces before and after the first `*` and no spaces before the second `*`?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious but wrong solution is

```
mv src/*[A-Z]* dest
```

However, the order of letters is locale dependent. `[A-Z]` therefore can contain lower case letters:

```
$> touch abc aBc
$> export LC_ALL=C
$> ls *[A-Z]*
abc
$> LC_ALL=en_US
$> ls *[A-Z]*
aBc abc
```

so make sure to set `LC_ALL` properly.

```
export LC_ALL=C
mv src/*[A-Z]* dest
```

BTW: `*[A-Z]*` is evaluated by the shell, not mv. Therefore the following *does not* work:

```
LC_ALL=C mv rc/*[A-Z]* dest   ## does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

This version ensure that only "Files" in root source folder are moved to target directory:

find /source/*[A-Z]* -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} /target \;